# Entity Framework Many to Many Relationship 3 Classes

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

Hi I have the three classes below. I'm trying achieve a many to many mapping with three classes. I have achieved many to many relationship between two classes but I'm trying to get another class in the mix. Below is the classes I have and a class representation of the relationship I'm trying to achieve.

```
public class Person
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Department> Departments { get; set; }
}

public class Department
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string DepartmentCode { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Person> Members { get; set; }
}

public class Role
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Any hints on how to achieve the below would be helpful.

```
public class PersonRoleDepartment
{
    public int PersonID { get; set; }
    public int DepartmentID{ get; set; }
    public int RoleID { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<PersonDepartmentRole> DepartmentRoles { get; set; }
}

public class Department
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<PersonDepartmentRole> PersonRoles { get; set; }
}

public class Role
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<PersonDepartmentRole> PersonDepartments { get; set; }
}

public class PersonDepartmentRole
{
    [Key, Column( Order = 0 )]
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey( "PersonId" )]
    [Required]
    public virtual Person Person { get; set; }

    [Key, Column( Order = 1 )]
    public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey( "DepartmentId" )]
    [Required]
    public virtual Department Department { get; set; }

    [Key, Column( Order = 2 )]
    public int RoleId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey( "RoleId" )]
    [Required]
    public virtual Role Role { get; set; }
}
```

Fluent API config:

```
var pdrConfig = modelBuilder.Entity<PersonDepartmentRole>()
    .HasKey( pdr => new
    {
        pdr.PersonId,
        pdr.DepartmentId,
        pdr.RoleId
    } ); 

pdrConfig.HasRequired( pdr => pdr.Department )
    .WithMany( d => d.PersonRoles )
    .HasForeignKey( pdr => pdr.DepartmentId );

pdrConfig.HasRequired( pdr => pdr.Person )
    .WithMany( p => p.DepartmentRoles )
    .HasForeignKey( pdr => pdr.PersonId );

pdrConfig.HasRequired( pdr => pdr.Role )
    .WithMany( r => r.PersonDepartments )
    .HasForeignKey( pdr => pdr.RoleId );
```

Note: all references from any of the primary entities to the others should route through your junction entity `PersonDepartmentRole` - if not, data inconsistencies can arise (e.g. I add a `Department` to a `Person` as well as a corresponding `PersonDepartmentRole` record to the DB, but then I remove the `Department` from the `Person` entity - the `PersonDepartmentRole` entity still remains)

Instead, if you want all departments for a person:

```
db.Person.DepartmentRoles.Select( dr => dr.Department ).Distinct()
```

Comment: Thanks. Can this only be achieved with the fluent api?

Comment: No, you can use data annotations if you like

Answer (score 0):

In this construct, can a person be in a department but have no role? Or, can a department play a role but has no people? If not, how could this be accomplished